# Ubuntu installation on hp dv2000

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, hp, amd-processor

I've been trying to get ubuntu to run on my hp dv 2000 with an amd turion x2 processor and an nvidia GeForce 7150M / nForce 630M card. The problem is that I am getting horizontal lines on the screen. and the power button which should be in the far right is on the far left of the screen. Display fails when I access dash home. i think there's a problem with the nvidia drivers. Also the wireless is not working. I tried to activate the broadcom wireless drivers in additional drivers but they do not activate. I am a complete newbie. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What specific wireless chip do you have? type lspci -vvnn and post results here.  Some b43 driver should work, after you supply the firmware (maybe in linux-firmware-nonfree package).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is with your graphic card

here is the soloution to resolve it

1. Remove all nVidia display drivers

   sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current nvidia-settings

   sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

   sudo apt-get clean

   and reboot
2. Installing drivers

   sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install nvidia-experimental-304

   sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings-experimental-304
3. run command at last
   sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current and  reboot

hope it helps

Comment: The graphics are working fine now. Thankyou. Any help regarding the wireless drivers.?

Answer (score 0):

For the Wireless, you have to have Internet connected through ethernet. I tried to activate hardware through "restricted drivers" before and it didn't work until I plugged into Ethernet. That was getting my WIFI going, though. I know nothing about the Graphics issue, never have had the graphics issue in the past. In ubuntu 12.04, make sure you have the wireless switch at the front turned on before pressing the power button, I had a Toshiba satellite L305D with Ubuntu 14.04, if I turned the switch off while in the OS, then turned it back on, it wouldn't recognize the adapter until I rebooted with the switch in the on position. Same thing with booting with it off, then trying to turn it on at the loggin. Ubuntu has gone through.... 28 versions? (Including the XX.10 ones) and they still can't get things fixed, but once you get it all spiffed up you'll like it.